# kendo angular changing dropdown option label

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

Before my kendo dropdown get populated with options, I want the optionLabel to be 'Wait for loading'. Then after it get populated I want to change the label to '--select--'.

My failed attempt:

html:

```
                    <select k-ng-disabled="table.LevelDropDown.disabled"
                            ng-disabled="table.LevelDropDown.disabled"
                            kendo-drop-down-list
                            k-data-text-field="'value'"
                            k-data-value-field="'GUID'"
                            k-options="table.LevelDropDown.options"
                            k-data-source="table.LevelDropDown.list"
                            k-ng-model="table.LevelDropDown.currentSelected"></select>
```

in controller (initial object state):

```
[...]

        LevelDropDown: {
            currentSelected: null,
            disabled: true,
            list: [{value: null, GUID: null}],
            options: {
                optionLabel: "Wait for loading"
            },
            resetFields: function () {
                $scope.LevelDropDown.currentSelected = null;
                $scope.LevelDropDown.list = [{ value: null, GUID: null }];
                $scope.LevelDropDown.disabled = true;
                $scope.LevelDropDown.options.optionLabel = "Wait for loading";

            }
```

Then somewhere in the code I would try to change the displaying label to '--select--'

```
 $scope.teamPermissions.addModalFields.OrgAccessLevelDropDown.options.optionLabel = "--Select--";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this function on `dataBound` event:

```
var changeOptionLabel = function(text) {
    var ddl = $("select").data("kendoDropDownList");
    ddl.optionLabel.text(text)
    ddl.options.optionLabel = text;
    ddl.refresh();
    ddl.select(0);
};
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/eNosu)

Comment: thanks, is there a way to do it without using jquery? Also can you explain why the way I did it fail to work?

Comment: @user308553 according to my tests, just changing the property `optionLabel` only changes the text after opening the list and only changes the option itself, not the item of the list. Take a look at [this demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/eNosu/3).

Comment: @user308553 in your case, try settinng the function as `dataBonud` event in your `options` object: `options: { dataBound: function() { ... } }` and change `dll`to `this`. It is clear ?